# data = null withRest (rest client) in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, httpbuilder

I'm having a problem with the HTTPBuilder rest client in grails. Code below:

```
withHttp(uri: "http://uclassify.com") {
                println "fetching comment sentiments for " + comment.content
                get(path : '/browse/uClassify/Sentiment/ClassifyText/', query : [readkey: key, text: comment.content, version: '1.01'], requestContentType: ContentType.XML){resp, data ->
                    println "data:"
                    println resp.getData()
                    println "status"
                    println resp.getStatus()
                    println "status line"
                    println resp.getStatusLine()
                    println "headers"
                    println resp.getAllHeaders()

                    println "data again"
                    println data        
                    println "finished"
                }
```

The headers return correctly compared with headers shown in firebug and curl, however the body of the response is always null. Content-length 383 would imply the server is returning the data (same size compared with header in firebug).

Here is the stdout that is produced.

```
fetching comment sentiments for something
data:
null
status
200
status line
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
headers
[Date: Fri, 26 Oct 2012 14:55:40 GMT, Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0, X-Powered-By: ASP.NET, X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727, Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=ipttqq55rini0t555i53zmvd; path=/; HttpOnly, Cache-Control: private, Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8, Content-Length: 383]
data again

finished
fetching comments complete
```

any ideas or recommendations?

Thanks